# True regex to catch wordpress subpage permalinks

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, preg-match

I have wordpress regex '(get/(.*)?)' which is working perfectly for following address.

```
http://localhost/akasia/get/gulets/for/sale/
```

My problem is this code is not matching for following url's

```
http://localhost/akasia/var/var/get/gulets/for/sale/

http://localhost/akasia/var/get/gulets/for/sale/var/

http://localhost/akasia/var/var/get/gulets/for/sale/var/var

http://localhost/akasia/n..0/var/var/get/gulets/for/sale/var/var/n..0
```

Regex buddy matches it but wordpress regex does not matching.

'.(get/(.*)?)', '(.?.+?)(get/(.*)?)' and various regex does not worked.

I did not understand why it is not working.

NOTE: When using $matches[] to retrieve the values of a matched URL, capture group data starts at 1, not 0.

Here is my code.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'create_rewrite_rule');
function create_rewrite_rule($rules){
    $newrules = array(
        '(get/(.*)?)' => 'index.php?&get=$matches[1]',
        //'for/([^/]+)?' => 'index.php?for=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $newrules + $rules;
}

function get_rewrite_rules(){
    // return get_option('rewrite_rules');
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    return $wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules();
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'create_query_vars');
function create_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'get';
    $vars[] = 'for';
    return $vars;
}

function get_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    $rules = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->wp_rewrite_rules();
    if (!isset($rules['(get/(.*)?)'])){ // must be the same rule as in create_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite)
        press('Regex kurallari guncellendi. Bu normal degil. Admin\'i haberdar edin.');
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
add_filter('init', 'get_flush_rewrite_rules');
```

**UPDATE** After days + hours, I found that regex buddy is true. following filter is not working true.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'create_rewrite_rule');
function create_rewrite_rule($rules){
    $newrules = array(
        '(get/(.*)?)' => 'index.php?get=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Instead of this you shoud use

```
function create_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*(get/(.*)?))', 'index.php?get=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'create_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

your code should be like this.

```
function create_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*(get/(.*)?))', 'index.php?get=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'create_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function get_rewrite_rules(){
    // return get_option('rewrite_rules');
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    return $wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules();
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'create_query_vars');
function create_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'get';
    $vars[] = 'for';
    return $vars;
}

function get_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    $rules = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->wp_rewrite_rules();
    if (!isset($rules['--(get/(.*)?)'])){ // must be the same rule as in create_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite)
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
add_filter('init', 'get_flush_rewrite_rules');
```

Hope helps some one.

Note : get_flush_rewrite_rules may not be necessary. I will check it out. Some test show me that add_rewrite_rule is doing that. I will make more tests and write to the here if I not forget.

Comment: I assume *akasia* is your wordpress directory. Then it looks like the regex needs "get/" at the very beginning. If I am right, you can just prepend it with .*

Comment: @AlexanderTaubenkorb akasia is my wp directory this is true. But regex does not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** After days + hours, I found that regex buddy is true. following filter is not working true.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'create_rewrite_rule');
function create_rewrite_rule($rules){
    $newrules = array(
        '(get/(.*)?)' => 'index.php?get=$matches[1]',
    );
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

Instead of this you shoud use

```
function create_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*(get/(.*)?))', 'index.php?get=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'create_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

your code should be like this.

```
function create_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('(.*(get/(.*)?))', 'index.php?get=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'create_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

function get_rewrite_rules(){
    // return get_option('rewrite_rules');
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    return $wp_rewrite->rewrite_rules();
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'create_query_vars');
function create_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = 'get';
    $vars[] = 'for';
    return $vars;
}

function get_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    $rules = $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->wp_rewrite_rules();
    if (!isset($rules['--(get/(.*)?)'])){ // must be the same rule as in create_rewrite_rule($wp_rewrite)
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
add_filter('init', 'get_flush_rewrite_rules');
```

Hope helps some one.

Note : get_flush_rewrite_rules may not be necessary. I will check it out. Some test show me that add_rewrite_rule is doing that. I will make more tests and write to the here if I not forget.